# tornado maps GET and POST arguments to lists. How can I disable this "feature"?

Tags: python, json, tornado, cyclone

The HTTPRequest class in the tornado* web framework helpfully [maps GET and POST arguments to lists](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/httpserver.py).  I understand why -- in case a given argument name is used multiple times.  But for some RequestHandlers, this is a pain.  For instance, if I want to pass a json object and parse it as-is on the server.

What's the most straightforward way to disable the map-to-list behavior so that I can send unaltered json to a tornado/cyclone server?

*Cyclone, actually, in case there's an implementation difference here.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Instead of accessing `self.request.arguments` directly you should use the accessor functions:

```
self.get_argument("ID", default=None, strip=False)
```

This returns a single item.

If you want to turn the arguments into a JSON object you can quite easily do so:

```
json.dumps({ k: self.get_argument(k) for k in self.request.arguments })
```

Comment: Thanks!  What if I just want to return the whole set of arguments as a single json object?  I could reconstruct it by iterating over the whole dictionary and calling get_argument for each key, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: json.dumps({ k: self.get_argument(k) for k in self.request.arguments }) - it's not really that inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go with "you're out of luck." You could re-write the class in question (looks like that would not be fun), but aside from that I don't see many options.

---

I would just use a dict comprehension.

```
{k:''.join(v) for k,v in  self.request.arguments.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Not avaliable in python 2.x

Comment: @V3ss0n `args = {'foo':('1','2','3',)};print {k:''.join(v) for k,v in args.iteritems()}` outputs `{'foo': '123'}` using 2.6+.

Comment: @cwallenpoole isn't it only in 2.7+? https://docs.python.org/2.7/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features

Comment: it's self.request.arguments